# Cometd Client not handshaking with cometD Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, cometd

I am new to CometD.I have a written a basic CometD Server in java and simple CometD Client.I am getting Successful response from postman for /meta/handshake,/meta/connect,/meta/subscribe channels. But when i start using my cometD java client(which i reused from the https://protect-us.mimecast.com/s/vLH6CNk58of1Ow1GsmVz4u?domain=github.com), handshake is failing with the below message.

> Failing {supportedConnectionTypes=[long-polling],
>   channel=/meta/handshake, id=22, version=1.0}

I am using cometdVersion - '4.0.0',jettyVersion - '9.4.0.v20161208',        springbootVersion - '1.5.14.RELEASE' in my code.
I have done a dynamic servlet registration to AnnotationCometDServlet and added /notifications as mapping.
I have created a channel as below in `bayeuxServer` configuration class.

```
bayeuxServerImpl.createChannelIfAbsent("/updates", 
(ServerChannel.Initializer) channel -> channel.addAuthorizer(GrantAuthorizer.GRANT_ALL));
```

In client code, i have used /notifications as the defaulturl and channel as /updates

```
@Service("cometListener")
@Slf4j
public class BayeuxListener implements BayeuxServer.SessionListener  {

@Inject
private BayeuxServer bayeuxServer;
@Session
private ServerSession serverSession;


@Configure({"/updates**,/notifications**"})
protected void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel) {
    channel.addAuthorizer(GrantAuthorizer.GRANT_ALL);
    channel.addAuthorizer(GrantAuthorizer.GRANT_PUBLISH);
    channel.setPersistent(true);
}

@Listener("/meta/*")
public void monitorMeta(ServerSession session, ServerMessage message) {
    log.info("monitoring meta"+message.toString()+"channel "+message.getChannel()+"session id "+session.getId());
}

@Listener("/meta/subscribe")
public void monitorSubscribe(ServerSession session, ServerMessage message) {      
    log.info("Monitored Subscribe from " + session + " for " + message.get(Message.SUBSCRIPTION_FIELD));
}

@Listener("/meta/unsubscribe")
public void monitorUnsubscribe(ServerSession session, ServerMessage message) {
    log.info("Monitored Unsubscribe from " + session + " for " + message.get(Message.SUBSCRIPTION_FIELD));
}

@Listener("/updates")
public void handlesrgUpdates(ServerSession client, ServerMessage message) {
    ServerSession cilentSession = bayeuxServer.getSession(client.getId());
    client.deliver(cilentSession,"/updates", "Received message back from client");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a strange combination of CometD version, Jetty version and Spring Boot version. I recommend that you stick with the default versioning declared in the [CometD POM](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/cometd/cometd-project/4.0.2/cometd-project-4.0.2.pom), i.e. CometD 4.0.2, Jetty 9.4.14 and Spring Boot 2.0.6.

The handshake failure you mention is not complete or it is not a failed handshake reply. This is because handshake replies have the `successful` field, and what you mention `{supportedConnectionTypes=[long-polling], channel=/meta/handshake, id=22, version=1.0}` looks like the handshake request. As such it's difficult to say what the problem is, because the failure reason is typically reported in the handshake reply.

If you have dynamically registered the CometD Servlet under the `/notifications` Servlet mapping, then the client should have a URL that ends with `/notifications`.
Note that the Servlet mapping `/notifications` and the CometD channel `/notifications` are two different things and are not related - they just happen to have the same name.

Your code is mostly fine, but contains a few errors.

```
@Configure({"/updates**,/notifications**"})
protected void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel) {
    channel.addAuthorizer(GrantAuthorizer.GRANT_ALL);
    channel.addAuthorizer(GrantAuthorizer.GRANT_PUBLISH);
    channel.setPersistent(true);
}
```

The code above must instead be:

```
@Configure({"/updates/**,/notifications/**"})
protected void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel) {
    channel.addAuthorizer(GrantAuthorizer.GRANT_ALL);
    channel.setPersistent(true);
}
```

Note that the channel globbing must be after a `/`.
There is no need to `GRANT_PUBLISH` after a `GRANT_ALL`, which include `GRANT_PUBLISH`.
The configuration method should be `public`, not `protected`.

```
@Listener("/updates")
public void handlesrgUpdates(ServerSession client, ServerMessage message) {
    ServerSession cilentSession = bayeuxServer.getSession(client.getId());
    client.deliver(cilentSession,"/updates", "Received message back from client");
}
```

There is no need to retrieve `clientSession` from `bayeuxServer` because it is already been passed as parameter `client` to the method.
The method can be better implemented as:

```
@Listener("/updates")
public void handlesrgUpdates(ServerSession client, ServerMessage message) {
    client.deliver(serverSession, "/updates", "Received message back from client");
}
```

Note how the "sender" of the message is the `serverSession` reference that has been injected as a field of the class.

The code above is still possibly wrong.
Because `/updates` is a broadcast channel, if the client is subscribed to the `/updates` channel, when the client publishes a message to the `/updates` channel it will receive it back from the server (because the client is subscribed to the `/updates` channel) and the code above will also send *another* message to the client on the `/updates` channel via `deliver()`, so the client will receive two different messages on the `/updates` channel.
This may be what you want, but most of the times it's not.
Please have a read at the [difference between broadcast channels and service channels](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_javascript_subscribe_service_channels).

Update the question with the details of your handshake failure, and use consistent versioning for CometD, Jetty and Spring Boot.

Comment: Thanks.After updating the CometD, Jetty and Spring Boot ,i am able to see the client handshake in server in session Listeners. I added a Security Policy to BayeuxServer Impl & overridden the canHandshake method. But i am not able to see the debugger hitting the canHandshake(). Could you please help me on this?

Comment: I want to add a map of ServerSession and unique user id on successful Authentication.

Comment: Troubleshooting discussions are not really meant for StackOverflow. You are welcome to join the [CometD mailing list](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_contribute_mailing_lists) or [file an issue](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/issues). Likely you are creating more than one `BayeuxServerImpl` instances during your startup, but in your question you don't show that part.

Comment: I also recommend you to start from the CometD Spring Boot example code, which works fine. You start from there, and then you modify it for your needs.